# MySQL Query like not returning correct results

Tags: mysql, collation, sql-like

i've a MySQL query that should return some rows that have the letters Ö or Ü in it
but it actually does not.

The query code is this:

```
$this->db->like('title', $text );
```

It's PHP CodeIgniter active query.

Lets assume we have 2 rows.
1. Büm
2. Bom

if i search for Bü, the 1. row has to be returned but it does not.
When i search for Bo the second row gets returned successfully and
when i search for B both rows are returned.

How could i fix this?
What may be the underlieng cause?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What happens with a search for 'Bu'?

Comment: Search for bu returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify a different collation in mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: Hello, the charset is set to UTF-8 now. Those are turkish characters